# Pasar elementos HTML a formulario con AJAX JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando pasar un input de un login que hice con AJAX y JavaScript, quiero pasarle el elemento HTML que introduzco en el formulario input `id=user` y llevarlo a otro fichero donde tengo un formulario con el `id=idrecolectororden`. Quiero pasarle dichos valores para luego accionar ese formulario, no encuentro la manera.

**Este es mi login:**

```html
<h1>Recolector</h1>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Nro Recolector" required>
<small class="form-text text-muted">Ingrese Usuario</small>
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="button"  id="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
<div>
    <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

El JavaScript del login esta en un script externo `../javascriptvalidacion/recolectores.js` y tiene el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#login').click(function(){
    var user = $('#user').val();

        if($.trim(user).length > 0){
            $.ajax({
                url:"../javascriptvalidacion/validarrecolector.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{'user':user},
                cache:false,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#login').val("Conectando...");
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#login').val("Login");
                    if (data="1"){
                        $(location).attr('href','../datoscliente.php');
                    } else {
                        $("#result").html("<div class='alert alert-dismissible alert-danger'><button type='button' class='close data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><strong>!error!</strong> las credenciles son incorrectas.</div>");
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    });
});
```

La manera que estoy intentando pasarle el valor de input `id=user` esta en el script `../javascriptvalidacion/recolectores.js` y tiene el siguiente código:

```
$('#login').click(function(){

    $.ajax({

        url:"../datoscliente.php",
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#user').text('Cargando..');
        },
        success : function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#user').html(data);
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Quiero enviarlo a este otro fichero con nombre `datoscliente.php` el código es el siguiente:

```html
<form  action="" method="POST">

    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id_recolectororden" id="id_recolectororden" placeholder="ID recolector" style="float:right;width:150px;height:40px;" required>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="fecha_orden"style="float:right;width:150px;height:40px;" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");?>" readonly>
    <button type="submit" name="ordengenerar" id="ordengenerar" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" style="width:150px;height:40px;">Generar Orden</button>

</form>
```

Al input de `id_recolectororden`.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien que es lo que estás intentando hacer, puedes dar un ejemplo de lo que tú código está haciendo, cuál es su resultado y que es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: hola enzo, enviarlos el input user, pasar esos datos al formulario que abro en datos clientes.php. en generar orden

Comment: el dato que ingreso en el login, en el input id=user, que ese dato que ingrese, llevarlo automaticamente al input del fichero de datoscliente.php y que se ponga solo en el input del formulario generar orden

Comment: estan en diferentes ficheros, eh ahi mi problema

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo haces con PHP? Supongo que el login funciona mediante sesiones, entonces usa variables de sesión para asignar/obtener los valores necesarios.